# How to load data before create VueJS app?

Tags: vue.js

I'm a little confused. How to load data (main.js file) and afrer (inside a component) set this data to data() function (calc.js)?

I have the data.json file:

```
{
    "store_data": "VUE_STORE",
}
```

I have the store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({

    state: {
        url_server: 'data.json',
        store_data: '',
    },
    actions: {
        getServerData({commit}){

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                Vue.http.get(this.state.url_server).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status == "200") {
                        commit('LOAD_SERVER_DATA', response)
                        resolve()
                    }
                });

            });

        }

    },

    mutations: {
        LOAD_SERVER_DATA (state, response) {
            this.store_data = response.data.store_data;
        },
    },

});
```

I have the main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import { store } from './store/store';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
import calc from './components/calc/calc';

Vue.use(VueResource);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    data: {},
    components: {
        'calc': calc,
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getServerData');
    }
});
```

And the component file calc.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'calc',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h1>calc</h1>
            <h2>{{test_value}}</h2>
        </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            test_value: 'AAA',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateTimer() {
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.test_value = this.$store.state.store_data;
/*        this.$store.dispatch('getServerData').then(() => {
            this.test_value = this.$store.state.store_data;
            console.log(this.$store.state.store_data);
        });*/
    },
    computed: {

    },
    mounted() {

    },

};
```

I'd like to set a test_value in calc.js file value this.$store.state.store_data. How it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use data for data owned by the store.  Use computed to return the store value, like so

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getServerData');
},
computed: {
    test_value(){
        return this.$store.state.store_data;
    }
},
mounted() {

},
```

And then in the vuex store the mutation has a little bug

```
mutations: {
    LOAD_SERVER_DATA (state, response) {
        state.store_data = response.data.store_data;
    },
```